# How to use react-native-config with a react native app build with Swift

Tags: swift, react-native, react-native-config

I am trying to use the [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) with react-native configured with Swift.

Following the usage guide, it tells me to import `#import "ReactNativeConfig.h"`.

I imported this inside of the bridging header, but it can't find it.

Does anyone know how to use this library with a react native app build with Swift?

Answer (score 2):

you just need to add `#import "ReactNativeConfig.h"` in bridging header. If you did that you can use it in your swift code without any additional import.

Here is some article I found helpful.
https://medium.com/@subhangdxt/bridging-objective-c-and-swift-classes-5cb4139d9c80

And here is my code:

My app-Bridging-Header.h:

```
...
#import "ReactNativeConfig.h"
...
```

My AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

  ...

  if let gmsApiKey = ReactNativeConfig.env(for: "GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY") {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey(gmsApiKey)
  } else {
    print("ERROR: No goole maps api key provided!")
  }

  bridge = RCTBridge(delegate: self,  launchOptions: launchOptions)

  ...

  return true
}
```